# Chrome - when i open a link from outlook chrome opens 4 extra tabs

Tags: google-chrome

when i open a link from outlook, chrome opens 4 extra tabs!

1 --extensions-on-chrome-urls/

2 --test-type/

3 --load-extension%3Dc/Program%20Files/Google/Chrome/Application/Extensions/chrome/app/37.1329.17.34

4 --load-component-extension%3Dc/Program%20Files/Google/Chrome/Application/Extensions/chrome/man

sorry cant post picture as i am new to this site.

Comment: If you upload the image to imgur and add a link someone will probably come along and edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  I was finally able to get rid of those extra tabs by:

1. Go to Chrome Task Manager
2. Find suspicious running extension (like TremendousSales)
3. End that process
4. Go to Chrome Extensions
5. Find the Extension just killed
6. Remove that extension

No more pesky tabs!